# Changing the params in URL on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to change the `:id` param on the URL. I added to my routes.rb file something like:

```
match "articles/:name/edit", :to => 'articles#edit', :as => 'edit_article'
```

Thinking that `:name` would be readed by the server as `params[:name]` later for me in rails. I edited my article controller definition for edit so:

```
def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:name])
end
```

I get always the error `couldn't find article with id=test` and I was wondering why "id" instead of :name? I tried also changing match to get but I got the same.

I have also the default resources :articles still in my routes.rb file, don't know if there's something like a *double rule* working there.

The whole thing is that instead of ID numbers I would use names in my URL —not just the edit one, with the show method I could handle it, but not with edit/update/delete.

I was [reading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) about routing but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `find` search by `id`.

You should replace it with `find_by_name`.

Advice: use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)